# accessing nested dictionary, that holds empty entries in python with get method and for loop that

Tags: python, dictionary

Assume you've got the following dictionary:

```
configuration = {'key1':{'thresholds': {"orange": 3.0, "red": 5.0}, {'plotSettings': {'yaxisscale': 'linear', "ylabel": "bar", 'ymin': 0}}, 'key2': {'thresholds': {"orange": 3.0, "red": 5.0}, 'plotSettings': {
        'yaxisscale': 'linear', "ylabel": "bar", 'ymin': 0}}, 'key3': {'thresholds': {"orange": 3.0, "red": 5.0}, 'plotSettings': {'yaxisscale': 'linear', "ylabel": "bar", 'ymin': 0}}}
```

All good with that

```
thresholds = {key:configuration[key]['thresholds'] for key in configuration}
```

But if some of the keys don't hold a threshold section I got the keyError.

```
configuration = {'key1':{'thresholds': {"orange": 3.0, "red": 5.0}, {'plotSettings': {'yaxisscale': 'linear', "ylabel": "bar", 'ymin': 0}}, 'key2': {'thresholds': {"orange": 3.0, "red": 5.0}, 'plotSettings': {
        'yaxisscale': 'linear', "ylabel": "bar", 'ymin': 0}}, 'key3': {'thresholds': {"orange": 3.0, "red": 5.0}, 'plotSettings': {'yaxisscale': 'linear', "ylabel": "bar", 'ymin': 0}}}

thresholds = {key:configuration[key]['thresholds'] for key in configuration}
```

The keyError as often described comes.

I tried to solve it this way:

```
thresholds = configuration.get(key, {}).get(
        'thresholds' for key in configuration)
```

But key is not known then.
How would you solve it.

Comment: As of now, `configuration` is an invalid data structure

Comment: Please fix your ```configuration``` dictionary. It is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add a check if `'thresholds'` exists

```
thresholds = {key: configuration[key]['thresholds'] for key in configuration if 'thresholds' in configuration[key]}
# {'key2': {'orange': 3.0, 'red': 5.0}, 'key3': {'orange': 3.0, 'red': 5.0}}
```

Using `get()` you can do something like

```
thresholds = {key: configuration[key].get('thresholds', {}) for key in configuration}
# {'key1': {}, 'key2': {'orange': 3.0, 'red': 5.0}, 'key3': {'orange': 3.0, 'red': 5.0}}
```

however this will leave an empty dictionary in `thresholds`.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a `try/except` clause inside your code.
Alternatively, you can use a `if` clause inside you List Comprehension:

1° method:

```
    try:
       thresholds = {key:configuration[key]['thresholds'] for key in configuration}
          ...some code ....
    
    except  keyError:
        print('threshold is empty')
```

2° method:

```
thresholds = {key:configuration[key]['thresholds'] if configuration[key]['thresholds'] is not None for key in configuration}
```

Comment: `except: pass` is a bad practice that should be avoided

Comment: `configuration[key]['thresholds'] is not None` will not work, if the `'thresholds'` doesn't exist you will get an exception, not to mention this code has an error and will not run.

Comment: @DeepSpace Obviously, but we have no information about user's errors management.

Comment: @Mark that does not mean we should suggest using a bad practice in answers. If you want more info, post a comment

Comment: @DeepSpace, I completely agree with you. I edited my answer. Thank you